# Writing generic methods for Selenium Page Object Model Framework

Tags: java, selenium

I'm following page object model where in I have placed all the WebElement addresses and methods  i.e id, xpath etc in the page.
Example:  On a login page we have username field, password field and login button. So all these will be on the LoginPage.java. This page includes the methods that use the Webelements as well. So from the actual test case I'm just calling methods that are defined on the page. Now here's my dilemma. I have several test steps that need me to click on an element. 
So say i need to click on Link1, Link2 and Link3. Right now what I'm doing is writing a separate method for each step and keeping them on the pagelike below:

```
@FindBy(id = "someId1")
WebElement link1;

@FindBy(id = "someId2")
WebElement link2;


public void clickOnLink1(){
    link1.click();
}

public void clickOnLink2(){
    link2.click();
}
```

Testcase:

```
clickOnLink1();

clickOnLink2();
```

So if i have 50 steps that need me to click on 50 different elements i would need 50 different methods and this is highly improper and inefficient. I could use a generic method like below:

```
public void clickOnElement(WebElement element) {
    element.click();
}
```

I can pass the element i want to be clicked to this method and it would do it for me.

Unfortunately as i said before I'm following page object model so all the WebElement addresses like id exist on the page and not on the test case hence i cannot use this method since i would need to pass the webelement from the test case.

Could someone please help me with a different approach.

Thank you

Comment: Can you give us a little info on why there are 50 different links? Are the links always on the page or are they dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like following:

```
public class Login_Page {


@FindBy(id = "someId1")
WebElement link1;

@FindBy(id = "someId2")
WebElement link2;

//constructor
public Login_Page(driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

//Generic Click method
public boolean genericClick(WebDriver driver, WebElement elementToBeClicked)
{

    try{

     elementToBeClicked.click();

     return true;
}
catch(Exception e){

     return false;
}

}
```

Now in the Test method:

```
@Test 
public void LoginTest()
{
 Webdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("someurl")

 Login_Page lp = new Login_Page(driver);
 lp.genericClick(driver, lp.link1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Login_Page {


private static WebElement element = null;


//username
public static WebElement Textbox_UserName (WebDriver driver)
{

    element = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));

    return element;

}
```

Now on the Test Case method just call this:

```
@Test 
public void Llogin()
{
 //initiate webdriver 
 //driver.get("url")
 Login_page.Textbox_UserName(driver).sendKeys("username")
}
```

Comment: same way you can do for any number of elements in you login page or any page.

Answer (score 0):

how about this, make your identifier static, and then call pass them from your test. Though I won't advice as then test can change the identifier and it would be hard to understand why test are failing.

**Your Page Object Class**

```
public class GoogleSearch {
    @FindBy(name="q")
    static WebElement searchBox;
    public GoogleSearch(WebDriver driver){
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
    public void enterText(WebElement element, String text){
        element.sendKeys(text);
    }
}
```

And this how your **test class** should look like

```
public class GoogleTest {

    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup(){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(){
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void SearchOnGoogle(){

        GoogleSearch googleSearchPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, GoogleSearch.class);
        googleSearchPage.enterText(GoogleSearch.searchBox, "selenium webdriver");

    }
}
```

To further refine you can have this **enterText** method in **BasePage** and each and every page object can Extend this **BasePage Class**

Answer (score 0):

```
`enter code here`    public class Rediffregistrationpage {
                      WebDriver driver;

                         public Rediffregistrationpage(WebDriver driver) {
                         this.driver=driver;
                          }
    
                         //method to enter the text in the text box 
                   public void Entertext(String labelname,int n,String text) {
             try {
         String  
        texts="//td[contains(text(),'"+labelname+"')]//following::input["+n+"]";
        //td[contains(text(),'Enter the text')]//following::input[1]
        By tex=By.xpath(texts);
        driver.findElement(tex).sendKeys(text);
        
    }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        
        //method to select element from dropdown
        
        public void selecttextfromdrop(String parameter,String value) {
            
            try {
            String par="//select[contains(@name,'"+parameter+"')]";
            WebElement para=driver.findElement(By.xpath(par));
            Select s=new Select(para);
            s.selectByVisibleText(value);
            
            
            
        }
            catch(Exception e) {
                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
            public void clickonlink(String text) {
                
                driver.findElement(By.linkText(text)).click();
                
            
        
        
}
            
            public void switchtotherwindow(int num) {
                Set<String>it=driver.getWindowHandles();
                Iterator<String>id=it.iterator();
                ArrayList<String>a=new ArrayList<String>();
                while(id.hasNext()) {
                a.add(id.next());
                
                }
                
                driver.switchTo().window(a.get(num));
                System.out.println(a.get(num));
                //driver.switchTo().window(a.get(Integer.parseInt(num)));
                System.out.println("Switched to   "+num+" window");
            }
            
            public void gettitleofpage() {
                String title=driver.getTitle();
                System.out.println("title is "+title);
                
            }
            public void clickonbutton(String clname) {
                driver.findElement(By.className(clname)).click();
            }
            public void validatetext(String textexpected,String tex) {
                
                String  textactual=driver.findElement(By.xpath(tex)).getText();
                Assert.assertEquals(textactual,textexpected);
                
                
                
                
                
            }
            
            
}



public class Testrediff {
    @Test
    public void registration() throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
        

         
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\chromedriver 
 _win32 (4)\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://register.rediff.com/register/register.php?F 
        ormName=user_details");
        Rediffregistrationpage red=new Rediffregistrationpage(driver);
        red.Entertext("Full Name", 1,"Mudaseer");
        red.Entertext("Mobile No", 2,"9845712345");
        red.selecttextfromdrop("DOB_Day", "05");
        red.selecttextfromdrop("DOB_Month", "MAY");
        red.selecttextfromdrop("DOB_Year", "2003");
        red.selecttextfromdrop("country", "India");
        red.selecttextfromdrop("city", "Bangalore");
        red.clickonlink("terms and conditions");
        
        red.switchtotherwindow(1);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        red.gettitleofpage();
        red.switchtotherwindow(0);
        red.gettitleofpage();
        red.clickonbutton("btn_checkavail");
        red.validatetext("The ID cannot be blank. Please choose your desired ID.","//b[contains(text(),'The ID')]");
        red.Entertext("Choose", 1,"##");
        red.clickonbutton("btn_checkavail");
        red.validatetext("The ID contains invalid character(s). Please choose 
           another ID.","//b[contains(text(),'The ID')]");
        
        
        


}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).